# how to make app with the Dynamic type support?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dynamic-type-feature

I have completed making an IOS app. Now its been final and was ready to upload, but suddenly I was given a task to apply a new thing in the app and that is as Under

> When user increases text size From the ***Settings > Accessibility > Larger Text*** or from ***Settings > Display And Brightness > TextSize*** now my app text appearance must change accordingly.

**What I want:**  As I told you above that app is completed, and as I have used too many UILabels, UIButtons and UITextViews, so I am finding a way to how to change their text size accordingly to newly changed text size by the user.  Is it possible to add any extension that increase the text size of app in more generic way. so that I do not have to go to every view in storyboard to make the view of dynamic type.

The process of changing and converting every view or coding in every class will be cumbersome. Is there any short way to handle it while everything is already completed.

Please help thanks.

Comment: You either need to change the storyboard or set the font using `preferredFont(forTextStyle:)` on each element.  There is no shortcut

Comment: how to set it using storyboard?

Comment: You have to click the "automatically adjusts font" box.  It is also best if you select a text style for the font.

Comment: You should also test your app with various dynamic type settings.  The new "Environment Overrides" screen in Xcode 11 makes this easy.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. but I was almost convinced that there will be someway to do so. Can you check out this link, I think he is trying to do same once for all 
https://medium.com/@rwbutler/dynamic-type-in-ios-with-typographykit-9ed0ac5dbf64

Answer (score 3):

> The process of changing and converting every view or coding in every class will be cumbersome. Is there any short way to handle it while everything is already completed.

I'm sorry to tell you that implementing the Dynamic Type feature in an already existing app is never easy and quick to be done.
It's like making the design, it takes time and requires conception for adapting the ergonomic a11y to provide the best user experience.

Even if many things can be done in the Interface Builder, I prefer to handle everything in code because you can mutualize many properties and methods while it's element by element in the IB.

Among other things, you'll have to:

- Use the **text styles** and activate the **adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory** properties of your elements to have an automatic update of your system font size.
- Listen to the **traitCollectionDidChange** method that belongs to the `UITraitEnvironment` informal protocol to be aware of the font size settings changes.
- Use **dynamic values** for adapting all your **constraints** so as to reorder appropriately every single element and make the containers fit their contents according to the different font size settings.
- Adapt and customize every **[Large Content Viewers](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-19261.html)** to enlarge UI elements when the Dynamic Type can't be applied *(only since iOS 13)*.

There's no magic trick to make an app with the Dynamic Type support: you have to know how it works and then build every element as you do in your daily programming.

Hereunder few links that may help to reach your goal:

- A [detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html) of the WWDC video 'Building Apps with Dynamic Type' where every steps are explained with a complete example in the end.
- Some [code snippets *(ObjC + Swift)* and illustrations](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#text-size) to provide explanations for code implementation.
- Few outlines to have in mind when [testing a Dynamic Type implementation](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/criteria-ios-test.html#DynamicType).

All these information could help you **make your app with the Dynamic Type support**.